# Multi-index dataframe with summarising rows

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to do a multilevel index dataframe looking like a pivot table with rows at a higher level showing aggregated numbers. Something like the output below

```
                   Points
Total                  10 
      Girls             3 
           TeamA        1
           TeamB        2
      Boys              7 
           TeamA        3
           TeamB        4
```

If this can be done straight away with the dataframe constructor by passing in the values and the index that would be even better. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

When you `print`, put this before whatever you want to print: `print (' '*spaces)+("whatever you so desire to print")`. Also create a string called `spaces` that tells it how many spaces you want. [Here is a website to help you](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/66055-changing-the-indentation-of-a-multi-line-string/).

Otherwise, I do not know a function that does that.

Comment: When you say "create a string called `spaces`", do you really mean an `int`?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems I did some progress on that. The closer I can get is the following, although no aggregation takes place. The values are simply passed in

```
In[2]: import pandas as pd
In[3]: import numpy as np
In[4]: idx = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[['Total', ''], ['Girls', 'Boys', ''], ['', 'TeamA', 'TeamB']],
              labels=[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[2,0,0,0,1,1,1],[0,0,1,2,0,1,2]])
In[5]: pd.DataFrame([10,3,1,2,7,3,4], index=idx, columns=['Points'])
Out[5]: 
                   Points
Total                  10
      Girls             3
            TeamA       1
            TeamB       2
      Boys              7
            TeamA       3
            TeamB       4
```